# E/UncaughtException: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, android

i'm keep getting this error while i'm trying to work with sectioned recyclerview adapter using [this](https://github.com/luizgrp/SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter) library.

Now here is whole stack trace i'm getting:

```
E/UncaughtException: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
                                                                        at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextEntry(HashMap.java:851)
                                                                        at java.util.HashMap$EntryIterator.next(HashMap.java:891)
                                                                        at java.util.HashMap$EntryIterator.next(HashMap.java:890)
                                                                        at io.github.luizgrp.sectionedrecyclerviewadapter.SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter.java:42)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6290)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5478)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5363)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5359)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2141)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1525)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1488)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:585)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3506)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3260)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3767)
                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:18793)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5952)
                                                                        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1079)
                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:18793)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5952)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1795)
                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:18793)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5952)
                                                                        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1079)
                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:18793)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5952)
                                                                        at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.layoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:1167)
                                                                        at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:852)
                                                                        at android.support.design.widget.ViewOffsetBehavior.layoutChild(ViewOffsetBehavior.java:63)
                                                                        at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.layoutChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:135)
                                                                        at android.support.design.widget.ViewOffsetBehavior.onLayoutChild(ViewOffsetBehavior.java:42)
                                                                        at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onLayoutChild(AppBarLayout.java:1375)
                                                                        at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:870)
                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:18793)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5952)
                                                                        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
                                                                        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:18793)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5952)
                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:18793)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5952)
                                                                        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
                                                                        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:18793)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5952)
                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:18793)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5952)
                                                                        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
                                                                        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
```

This is some part of the code from his library where error is produced:

```
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
    View view = null;

    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : sectionViewTypeNumbers.entrySet()) {
        if (viewType >= entry.getValue() && viewType < entry.getValue() + VIEW_TYPE_QTY) {

            Section section = sections.get(entry.getKey());
            int sectionViewType = viewType - entry.getValue();

            switch (sectionViewType) {
                case VIEW_TYPE_HEADER: {
                    Integer resId = section.getHeaderResourceId();

                    if (resId == null)
                        throw new NullPointerException("Missing 'header' resource id");

                    view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(resId, parent, false);
                    // get the header viewholder from the section
                    viewHolder = section.getHeaderViewHolder(view);
                    break;
                }
                case VIEW_TYPE_FOOTER: {
                    Integer resId = section.getFooterResourceId();

                    if (resId == null)
                        throw new NullPointerException("Missing 'footer' resource id");

                    view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(resId, parent, false);
                    // get the footer viewholder from the section
                    viewHolder = section.getFooterViewHolder(view);
                    break;
                }
                case VIEW_TYPE_ITEM_LOADED: {
                    view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(section.getItemResourceId(), parent, false);
                    // get the item viewholder from the section
                    viewHolder = section.getItemViewHolder(view);
                    break;
                }
                case VIEW_TYPE_LOADING: {
                    Integer resId = section.getLoadingResourceId();

                    if (resId == null) throw new NullPointerException("Missing 'loading state' resource id");

                    view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(resId, parent, false);
                    // get the loading viewholder from the section
                    viewHolder = section.getLoadingViewHolder(view);
                    break;
                }
                case VIEW_TYPE_FAILED: {
                    Integer resId = section.getFailedResourceId();

                    if (resId == null) throw new NullPointerException("Missing 'failed state' resource id");

                    view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(resId, parent, false);
                    // get the failed load viewholder from the section
                    viewHolder = section.getFailedViewHolder(view);
                    break;
                }
                default:
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid viewType");
            }
        }
    }

    return viewHolder;
}
```

And finally my part where i'm fetching data from server DB and showing inside recyclerview with sections. Somewhere i'm making a mistake and hope someone will point me to the right direction. So here it is:

```
if (!response.getBoolean("error")) {
                dates.clear();
                originalList.clear();
                mEvents.clear();
                mSectionedRecyclerViewAdapter.removeAllSections();
                mSectionedRecyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                JSONArray eventsArray = response.getJSONArray("events");

                for (int i = 0; i < eventsArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject eventObj = eventsArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    Event event = new Event();

                    if (eventObj.getInt("field_id") != 0) {
                        Field field = new Field();
                        field.setId(eventObj.getInt("field_id"));
                        field.setAddress(eventObj.getString("field_address"));
                        field.setName(eventObj.getString("field_name"));

                        if (!eventObj.isNull("field_contact")) {
                            field.setMobileNumberFirst(eventObj.getString("field_contact"));
                        }

                        if (!eventObj.isNull("score")) {
                            field.setReviewScore(eventObj.getDouble("score"));
                            field.setReviewNum(eventObj.getInt("review_num"));
                        }

                        event.setField(field);
                        location = event.getField().getAddress();
                        event.setLocation(location);
                    } else {
                        event.setLocation(eventObj.getString("event_location"));
                        location = eventObj.getString("event_location");
                    }

                    double distanceInKm = Double.parseDouble(eventObj.getString("distance_km"));
                    int distanceInMet = eventObj.getInt("distance_m");

                    if (distanceInKm >= 1) {
                        event.setDistance(distanceInKm + " km");
                    } else {
                        event.setDistance(distanceInMet + " m");
                    }

                    dates.add(event.getDatetime().substring(0, 10));
                    mEvents.add(event);
                }

                // add elements to al, including duplicates
                Set<String> hs = new LinkedHashSet<>();
                hs.addAll(dates);
                dates.clear();
                dates.addAll(hs);

                Collections.sort(dates, new Comparator<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public int compare(String s, String t1) {
                        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                        try {
                            return sdf.parse(s).compareTo(sdf.parse(t1));
                        } catch (ParseException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        return 0;
                    }
                });



                for (String date : dates) {
                    originalList = getEventsWithDate(date);

                    if (formattedDate.equals(date)) {
                        date = "Danas";
                    } else {
                        int monthOfYear = 0;
                        Date startDate;
                        try {
                            startDate = myDateFormat.parse(date);

                            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                            calendar.setTime(startDate);
                            monthOfYear = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                        } catch (ParseException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        String month = getMonth(monthOfYear);

                        try {
                            String monthNum = date.substring(8, 10);
                            date = monthNum + " " + month;
                        } catch (Exception ignored) {

                        }
                    }

                    if (originalList.size() > 0) {
                        Collections.sort(originalList, new Comparator<Event>() {
                            @Override
                            public int compare(Event event, Event t1) {
                                return event.getDateFromString().compareTo(t1.getDateFromString());
                            }
                        });
                        if (matchType == 3) {
                            mSectionedRecyclerViewAdapter.addSection(new EventSection(R.layout.lst_item_event_v4, date, originalList, getActivity(), matchType));
                        } else {
                            mSectionedRecyclerViewAdapter.addSection(new EventSection(R.layout.lst_item_event_v2, date, originalList, getActivity(), matchType));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: still parsing json with JSON object? My friend, use any Jackson or Gson library

Comment: can you share SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter.onCreateViewHolder code because it seems to this is issue because of you are trying to modify the value of HashMap inside Loop.

Comment: @ChintanRathod I used to go with JSON object. I will start using some of these two libraries on my next project.

Comment: @VikasTiwari Hello, i have edited my question. You can see onCreateViewHolder now. But it was the second part. I think error is coming from my part of code, not from his.

Comment: Are you using a different thread for adding the section ?

Comment: No, when one thread is finished, i'm starting new. You can see that from my code. But i will explain how my logic works. In first thread i'm storing in array list dates and preparing data which will be grouped by dates. In second thread i'm iterating through dates array list and in method `getEventsWithDate()` i'm searching for records with given date. After that adding that record to new list `originalList` and adding that original list to the section adapter, and also putting given date.

Comment: mSectionedRecyclerViewAdapter.addSection(new EventSection(R.layout.lst_item_event_v4, date, originalList, getActivity(), matchType)); For this line which thread are you using ? main thread or background thread

Comment: @Krish Second, because i need to go through all dates

Comment: I think this two lines (if else) making your app crash .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141424/discussion-between-krish-and-dusan-dimitrijevic).